# Count frequency of records and join with other tables as new columns for each type

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, join

I am trying to compose a table by joining different columns from different tables (e.g. "case", "patient" and "journal" tables). In the journal table, I have one column named "type". For each entry (record) in the journal, the record is coded from 1-3 depending on the type of journal entry. I want to count the total number of each type for each patient, and join the results with the rest of my postgresql-query.

A simplified version of the journal table looks like this:

| PatientID | Type | CaseNr |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 250 |
| 1 | 3 | 250 |
| 1 | 1 | 250 |
| 2 | 2 | 400 |
| 2 | 3 | 400 |
| 2 | 3 | 400 |

Joining the other columns is an ok task (this is simplified as I really have a lot more tables and columns):
`SELECT case.patient, patient.age from case, patient where case.patient=patient.nr group by case.patient, patient.age`

However, I can't resolve how to include the frequency of the different types from the journal table (note: as their own columns, not additional rows for every patient!). Adding `SELECT count(journal.type) as "type1", count(journal.type) as "type2" FROM journal WHERE type1='1' and type2='2'` etc. obviously didn't work, but maybe it can give a clue to what I want. I also want to join the tables on caseNr, which is the key in this case.

So I want the final table to e.g. look something like this:

| Patient ID | Age | Type 1 frequency | Type 2 frequency | Type 3 frequency |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 13 | 2 | 0 | 1 |
| 2 | 7 | 0 | 1 | 2 |

All help is very much appreciated!

Comment: If the number of "types" is known, try using a conditional sum, i.e. `sum(case when type=1 then 1 else 0 end) as Type1Frequency, repeat for other types....` and grouping the results by patient id

Answer (score 0):

Syntax may need some cleaning up but PIVOT may be a good option

```
Select PatientID,[Type 1 Frequency],[Type 2 Frequency],[Type 3 Frequency]
from
(
select  PatientID,Type as TypeFreq
from Table1
) as Src
Pivot
(
count(Type)
For [TypeFreq] in ([Type 1 Frequency],[Type 2 Frequency],[Type 3 Frequency])
) as Pvt
```